# Accesing arrays to make dropdownlist choice for user , while importing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am importing such a file which is an object

```
 const exercisePack = {
    squatExerciseMain,
    randomPackLegsBasic,
    randomPackUpperBodyAndAbdomen,
    randomPackUpperBodyChestAndArms,
   ...
  };
```

each of these variables is an array with objects

```
const pullExercisesBodyweightVertical = [
    new AccessoryExercise('Pull-ups',[3,10],['forearm', 'arms', 'upperback', 'shoulders'],['pull', 'bilateral']),
    new AccessoryExercise('Pull-ups neutral grip',[3,10],['forearm', 'arms', 'upperback', 'shoulders'],['pull', 'bilateral']),
...
].
```

I want to use them in a way that they will be accesible in a dropdownlist and with reducer in this component

```
<tr className="Accesories">
          <td> <h3>II. {accesoryExerciseFirst.name} </h3> </td>  
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <button className={classes.IncrementationButton} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT_SETS", exercise: "accesoryExerciseFirst" })}> - </button>
            <h3> {state.accesoryExerciseFirst.sets} </h3>
            <button className={classes.IncrementationButton} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT_SETS", exercise: "accesoryExerciseFirst" })}> + </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button className={classes.IncrementationButton} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT_REPS", exercise: "accesoryExerciseFirst" })}> - </button>
            <h3> {state.accesoryExerciseFirst.reps} </h3>
            <button className={classes.IncrementationButton} onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT_REPS", exercise: "accesoryExerciseFirst" })}> + </button>
          </td>
          </tr>
```

how can i change the accessory exercise , using a reducer , knowing that each accesory has its own sets and reps , and that this state will also have to be updated when the change is being made ?

this is the reducer at the moment

```
function exerciseReducer(state:any, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_MAIN_EXERCISE":
      return {
        ...state,
        mainExercise: action.exercise
      };
      
    case "CHANGE_ACCESSORY_EXERCISE":
      return {
        ...state,
        accessoryExercise: action.exercise
      };
      
    case "INCREMENT_SETS":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.exercise]: {
          ...state[action.exercise],
          sets: state[action.exercise].sets + 1
        }
      };
    case "DECREMENT_SETS":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.exercise]: {
          ...state[action.exercise],
          sets: state[action.exercise].sets - 1
        }
      };
    case "INCREMENT_REPS":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.exercise]: {
          ...state[action.exercise],
          reps: state[action.exercise].reps + 1
        }
      };
    case "DECREMENT_REPS":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.exercise]: {
          ...state[action.exercise],
          reps: state[action.exercise].reps - 1
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```